# Copy format of previous row when Gforms is submitted

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

When I submitted a Google forms, I would like copy paste the format of row n°3 (considered as reference) in last line created by the form submissions in the google sheet "responses".
Hereafter my code:

```
function CopyFormatting() {
//Déclaration des variables
var SheetResponse = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); //Sheet of forms response
var LastRow = SheetResponse.getLastRow(); //last row of sheet (n)
var RefRow = SheetResponse.getRange("3:3"); //Row n°3 considered as reference

//Copy formatting to last row from reference row
RefRow.copyTo(LastRow, {formatOnly: true});
}
```

Thank you in advance for support

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- You want to copy the format from the row 3 to the last row on the active sheet.
- You want to run the function `CopyFormatting()`, when the Google Form was submitted.

  - Your script is the container-bound script of Spreadsheet which put the values from Google Form.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `LastRow` of `RefRow.copyTo(LastRow, {formatOnly: true})` is the number. In this case, please use the range object.
- In order to run the function `CopyFormatting()` when the Google Form was submitted, [please install the OnSubmit event trigger to the function `CopyFormatting()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually).

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

From:

```
RefRow.copyTo(LastRow, {formatOnly: true});
```

To:

```
RefRow.copyTo(SheetResponse.getRange(LastRow, 1), {formatOnly: true});
```

#### Note:

- If you want to copy the format to the next row of the last row, please modify `getRange(LastRow, 1)` to `getRange(LastRow + 1, 1)`.
- In your script, `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()` is used. So in this case, the 1st tab is used. If you want to run the script to the specific tab in the Spreadsheet, please use `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("### sheet name ###")` instead of that.
- If you want to copy the format of the previous row of the last row to the last row, please modify to `var RefRow = SheetResponse.getRange(SheetResponse.getLastRow() - 1, 1, 1, SheetResponse.getLastColumn())`.

#### References:

- [copyTo(destination, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-options)
- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: The function is now OK with the code`RefRow.copyTo(SheetResponse.getRange(LastRow, 1), {formatOnly: true});`
Thank you for all explanation

Comment: @Mohamed H Is there anything that I can do for your question? If my answer was not useful for your situation. I have to apologize and modify it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. I would like to think of about the solution.

Comment: The solution is OK. Sorry I have forgotten to accept the solution.

Comment: @Mohamed H Thank you for your response. I'm glad your issue was resolved.